# Car stops in Modern Combat 3 on Android, level 5 after the helo

Tags: android, modern-combat-3

In the shoot from the truck level 5, the car stops, and I don't know what to do.

Just after the grenade launcher pops into my hand, blow up the car, and drive over a river.  The driver says something about a helo. Then the car stops.

There is no one I can see to kill, and I don't know how to get out of the car, or get it moving again.

Is it a crashed game?  Am I missing something? What do I do? Or is there a cheat to get to level 6 as I don't like the moving vehicle levels anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It was just a glich in the game.  I played a couple more times.  Once I didnt destroy the truck chasing me, and it drove off down the river.  And the car continued about a meter than in was stopping and stopped in front of a helicopter.  Kill them etc....

Good game but i do find myself getting stuck on the scenery or not being able to jump over little things.  annoying glitches....